# Link in user profile wants to install PUPs (potentially unwanted programs)

Tags: support, new-users, profile-page

**WARNING: Follow the links mentioned here with care**.

The profile description for new user [Solenodon Paradoxus](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/24871/solenodon-paradoxus), has [a link to his/her blog at solenodus dot com](http://solenodonus.com/) which redirects to reps.appcase.com, which then does a 'Are you a human check' and then wants to install a 'Safe Browsing Extension' into my FireFox browser.

<strike>Things like these are a big **NO-NO** in my book.

Does someone need to undertake action?</strike>

**Hold the press**. I thought I'd try a second time, to check if this was cookie-controlled, and happens only one time. Now I get redirected to https://google-nl.promotioneleprijs.pw

Someone needs to undertake action. At a minumum his blog is hacked, at a maximum this is someone with bad intentions.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if this is similar: [I clicked on an imgur link in an SE chat room and ended up at a url in India with a screen that looked like Google; what happened?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/192328/115702)

Comment: @uhoh That sounds like malvertising, possibly in combination with ISP advert injection; this sounds like site takeover. Similar in the sense that it's all malware. BTW that blog domain is now down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for letting us know about this. I've edited the links out of the user's profile and have privately let them know about the issue. As far as I can tell from looking [at archived versions of the page](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022034959/http://solenodonus.com:80/), the domain was originally actively used by this person, but has since lapsed, so I think this problem wasn't malicious - but certainly something we needed to address.

It turned out that the user was unaware that the domain had lapsed, and the mistake was indeed innocent. All's well that ends well.